# regular expressions explanation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can somebody explain what this regular expression does?

```
document.cookie.match(/cookieInfo=([^;]*).*$/)[1]
```

Also it would be great if I can strip out the double quotes I'm seeing in the cookieInfo values. i.e. when cookieInfo="xyz+asd" - I want to strip out the double quotes using the above regular expression.

Comment: You can also do it your self: [Regex CheatSheat](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) =)

Comment: The `.*$` is useless.

Comment: This is odd . . . the `[1]` at the end indicates that the code wants the second match returned in the array, but there is no `g` at the end of the Regex pattern, so there would never be more than one match (represented by `[0]`, not `[1]`) . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It searches the document.cookie string for `cookieInfo=`.
Next it grabs all of the characters which are not `;` (until it hits the first semicolon).
`[...]` set of all characters included inside.
`[^...]` set of all characters which don't match

Then it lets the RegEx search through all other characters.
`.*` any character, 0 or more times.
`$` end of string (or in some special cases, end of line).

You could replace `"` a couple of different ways, but rather than stuffing it into the regex, I'd recommend doing a replace on it after the fact:

```
var string = document.cookie.match(...)[1],
    cleaned_string = string.replace(/^"|"$/g, "");
```

That second regex says "look at the start of the string and see if there's a `"`, or look at the end of the string and see if there's a `"`.
Normally, a RegEx would stop after it did the first thing it found.  The `g` at the end means to keep going for every match it can possibly find in the string that you gave it.

I wouldn't put it in the original RegEx, because playing around with optional quotes can be ugly.
If they're guaranteed to always, always be there, then that's great, but if you assume they are, and you hit one that doesn't have them, then you're going to get a `null` match.

Answer (score 2):

It basically saying grab as many characters that are not semi-colons and that follow after the string 'cookieInfo='

Try this to eliminate the double quotes:

```
document.cookie.match(/cookieInfo="([^;]*)".*$/)[1]
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily recommend this, if the quotes aren't guaranteed to be there 100% of the time. If they're ever not there, you're going to get a `null` match. You could deal with an optional leading quote easily `/cookieInfo="?(...` but then you might get leftover closing `"` which is no good. The solution which adapts to optional ending quotes is going to be uglier and more confusing to someone who doesn't do RegEx normally.  My suggestion is to replace them after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression matches a string starting with 'cookieInfo=' followed by and capturing 0 or more non-semi-column characters followed by 0 or more 'anythings'.

To strip out the double quotes you can use the regex /"/ and replace it with an empty string.